# How does server count time for "504 gateway time-out error"?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm new with web service. I'm using Oracle Jdeveloper to call web service to request data. I need to call the function they provided for about 40,000 times. I use a while loop and it erratically returns "504 gateway time-out" error or "500 server error". By "erratically"  I mean sometimes it caught exception after 500 calls but sometimes just after several calls or even at the beginning.

What I've tried: reduce the total number of calls but increase the requested data amount for each call. But the result seems like I got the error more frequently (after 2 or 3 queries).

My question is: How does the server count time? Is the time-out server error related to "time" or to "frequency"? Is there a way to avoid this error?

---

#### Solution

I just reduced the call frequency and when this error popped up, asked for waiting and recall after 30 sec.

Comment: I think "gateway timeout error" really means that the service behind a reverse proxy crashed and isn't responding.

Comment: 500 and 504 are special code and do not represent the number of try see more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Can you try staggering the calls by 1 second?